# WebService Request Success but fails the Response-Best Design Principle

Tags: java, web-services

Assume , "Application1" wants to make a a Web service call to a Banking System and update a record. There can be a situation where Http Request success and Banking database update in the way it expects. But response fails may be due to may be communication error.

```
Results : As the "Application1" has not received the response, it assumes that DB has not updated.

Possible Solution.
1. There will be a TimeOutException from the "Application1". Then make a  DBQuery check the record is updated or not inside the exception block. If it has not re-try it.

1. What happens if all re-tries does not receive the reponse. 
2. I see some theories related to Web Service Transaction , Service Ochastration. 
Any other better solutions. ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is with messaging systems. In your case, WebService will be expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: Hi Agree. Asynchronous messaging is a best solution. Let me change my problem specification a little bit. In case if I want to make the Web Service Request, through bank's Service API , what would be the best way to handle Web-Service Response failures.